# Linkedin API Acess

Tags: linkedin-api

I am able to authenticate using OAuth and have access to these scopes profile, email, w_member_social, and opened. However when I try to access the profile data I get below error

Profile Data: {'serviceErrorCode': 100, 'message': 'Not enough permissions to access: GET /me', 'status': 403}

any help in resolving the same will be appreciated.